# VB .NET run a thread at specified time everyday

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, timer, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to run a background thread every 24 hours but I would like to run it at specific time say 10 am everyday.

```
 Private Sub StartBackgroundThread()
    Dim threadStart As New Threading.ThreadStart(AddressOf DoStuffThread)
    Dim thread As New Threading.Thread(threadStart)
    thread.IsBackground = True
    thread.Name = "Background DoStuff Thread"
    thread.Priority = Threading.ThreadPriority.Highest
    thread.Start()
End Sub
```

Rather than simply do a sleep for 24 hours as below, I need the thread to be called when 10 am is reached. I know a way may be checking something like Hour(Date.Now) = 10 and Minute(Date.Now) = 0, but I guess it is not a proper way to do this.

```
Private Sub DoStuffThread()
    Do
        DO things here .....
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Since you already tagged it `scheduled-tasks` why do you even try to reinvent the wheel instead of just use the built-in Scheduler Windows provides?

Comment: Answer for your question is use scheduled-tasks. Also why `Background DoStuff Thread` have `ThreadPriority.Highest`?

Comment: @Filburt I am new to VB and not very sure which way to go. Could you give me an example in terms of my case using task scheduler? Thanks

Comment: @wuha Creating a scheduled task on the Windows platform doesn't require any programming knowledge - see [Schedule a task](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7) to get started. Your VB programm will be the action the task is going to execute at the configured trigger (10 am every day).

Comment: @Filburt Well, actually I need to do it programatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running a good scheduler application would be your best bet. You don't need to write your own.

I don't see why you would want to set thje Priority to high.

There are better ways to do this, but here's a quick example that need little modification on your code.
The idea is to store the next execution date and see if the current date was passed it.

```
Private Sub DoStuffThread()
    Dim nextExecution As DateTime

    nextExecution = DateTime.Now
    nextExecution = New DateTime(nextExecution.Year, nextExecution.Month, nextExecution.Day, 10, 0, 0)

    If nextExecution < DateTime.Now Then nextExecution = nextExecution.AddDays(1)

    Do
        If nextExecution < DateTime.Now Then
           DO things here .....
           nextExecution = nextExecution.AddDays(1)
        End If

        Threading.Thread.Sleep(60 * 1000) ' Just sleep 1 minutes
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it will be simpler to do it this way:

```
Private Sub DoStuffThread()
    Do
        If DateTime.Now.Hour = 10 And DateTime.Now.Minute = 0 Then
            DO things here .....
        End If
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(60 * 1000) ' Sleep 1 minute and check again
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: this is genius. It gets rid of the need for scheduler... provided you don't have memory leaks over long periods of time. NOTE that 0 is midnight. 23 is 11pm. first minute is 0. last minute is 59. Seems obvious but it never hurts to know these things.